# Need help in proving this expression

Tags: calculus

This is a question from antenna and theory book.
Need to prove that this equation $$D = \frac{{{{\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {{A_k}} } \right)}^2}}}{{\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{N - 1} {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {{A_m}{A_p}\left( {\frac{{\sin \beta \left( {{z_m} - {z_p}} \right)}}{{\beta \left( {{z_m} - {z_p}} \right)}}} \right)} } }}$$

reduces to $$D = \frac{{{{\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {{A_k}} } \right)}^2}}}{{\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{N - 1} {A_m^2} }}$$

When $$d = \frac{{n\lambda }}{2}$$ and $${z_m} - {z_p} = \left( {m - p} \right)\frac{\lambda }{2}$$
the term
$$\frac{{\sin \beta \left( {{z_m} - {z_p}} \right)}}{{\beta \left( {{z_m} - {z_p}} \right)}} = \frac{{\sin \frac{{2\pi }}{\lambda }\left( {m - p} \right)\frac{\lambda }{2}}}{{\frac{{2\pi }}{\lambda }\left( {m - p} \right)\frac{\lambda }{2}}} = \frac{{\sin \left( {m - p} \right)\pi }}{{\left( {m - p} \right)\pi }}$$

By putting this value to the first equation, how does D reduce to 2nd equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did most of the work. if $m\neq p$, then 
$$\frac{{\sin \beta \left( {{z_m} - {z_p}} \right)}}{{\beta \left( {{z_m} - {z_p}} \right)}} = \frac{{\sin \left( {m - p} \right)\pi }}{{\left( {m - p} \right)\pi }} = 0$$
Whereas if $m=p$, that term is equal to 1.

Comment: how is this term equal to 1 when m=p.

Comment: Technically it's $0/0$, which is undefined.  But it's 1 in the sense that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(x)/x = 1$